# Having issues with the Swiper jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a website for a client, and I am fairly new in JavaScript and jQuery. I need help with the Swiper jQuery plugin. I am using their way which automatically detects and assigns the links to the slides, but I am not satisfied with it. I am trying to figure out how to link each link in my menu manually with a slide. The website is going to be static, so that will be okay. Here is their API:

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

I know this is the right option, but don't know how to use it: `mySwiper.swipeTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)` - "run transition to the slide with index number equal to 'index' parameter for the speed equal to 'speed' parameter. You can set 'runCallbacks' to false (by default it is 'true') and transition will not produce onSlideChange callback functions."

I got this HTML code:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" index="1">
    <div class="content-slide">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the index parameter with the value of 1 to the slide, as described in their api, than used this code:

```
$(".logo").click(function() {
    tabsSwiper.swipeTo(1)
});
```

But, it's not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Is the semicolon missing intentionally from tabSwiper.swipeTo(1);?

Comment: Check your javascript debugger to see what error you get.